# python Flask mail is not sending local image as mail body.

Tags: python, email, flask

I am trying to send email from my flask app with images and some text as body of the email. I am able to send emails with images when I used to external image links, but I am receiving broken image mail when i used local images.

I stored my images in /static/image/image.jpg;

here is message.html

```
msg.html = "<img src='/static/img/image.jpg' style='width:500px;height:228px;'>"
```

Answer (score 3):

Pass full your to the images on your server, which is accessible openly on the internet. Like:

```
<img src='http://example.net/static/img/image.jpg' style='width:500px;height:228px;'>
```

If your image is not accessible by the email client, it will not load.

#### Why do we need to do this?

Because the receivers email client will want to load that image from an URL. But if you just pass a relative path, `/static/img/image.jpg`, the client will not be able to load the image.

And then there are clients like Gmail, who downloads the image and then serve it their own way to prevent different malicious attacks.

So we always need to provide an address that is accessible properly on the internet.

Comment: That makes sense... I am running my application in the local system with localhost:5000. I think i will never be able to send image from my static image folder. I might need to link to global images, which are accessible by every mail client on the net.

Comment: You can use a service like `ngrok` to test locally. `ngrok` would share your local server on the internet so it's accessible by the email clients.

Comment: Does `src="{{ url_for('static', filename='img/image.jpg') }}"` work for you?